# Wild Card Certificate assignment

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a wild card certificate, but I cannot assign it to a custom domain configured on my webapp. The wild card certificate is issued to *.foo.com. I want to assign this certificate to  pqr.bar.foo.com which is already configured as a custom domain  on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wildcard certificate issued to *.foo.com will work for subdomains of the type {****}.foo.com (bar.foo.com, www.foo.com, stu.foo.com), and not {****}.{****}.foo.com (pqr.bar.foo.com).